# Codeblocks is not installed from Ubuntu Software

Tags: software-installation

I was trying to install two software previously. But they are not installed in my system. But then there a notification in the installed [image: 1] tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install CodeBlocks [packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/codeblocks) using terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get install codeblocks codeblocks-contrib
```

Comment: but I want to know another thing. Why 2 is shown beside the Installed tab?

Comment: It may be a bug in Ubuntu Software application.